# Jackson error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Versioned

Tags: java, json, jackson, ejb

I am working on Maven-EJB and want to convert a java object to JSON, I use Jackson jars lib but I got:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned

I added these dependencies in pom.xml file:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.0</version>
>     </dependency>        
> </dependencies>
> ```

in Java Facade I write this lines to convert:

> String json = "";
>
> ```
>     try {
>          ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
>          json = ow.writeValueAsString(userlist);
>     } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
>         throw new BusinessException("error_json");
>     }
> ```

and here is the imports:

> import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException; import
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; import
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;

I checked the classpath and make a lot of clean and build but no way,,,the same exception appear!!

I am working on NetBeans8 and Java 1.7

Thanks in advance
Mariam

Comment: maybe your imports are in conflict with another version packaged in your application server ?

Comment: How can I check this?!! it is a simple application!

Comment: No matter how simple is your app, if you use EJBs, you need an application server like JBoss or Websphere. Check which version you use and which libraries/version are provided. To do that, you can browse the server directory or check the documentation.

Comment: I am using glassfish 3.0

Comment: also jackson jars version is 2.4.0

Comment: I don't know much about glassfish 3.0 modularity. But apparently, it is shipped with jackson-asl 1.1.1. try switching from 2.4.0 to 1.1.1. Switch the scope to <scope>provided</scope>

Comment: also you don't need all these dependencies just to serialize an object. I think all you need is 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.1.1'

Comment: Thanks Couettos, it works, I checked the versions and I download the 2.4.0 jackson jars and upgrade the glassfish lib jars with the 2.4.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Couettos, it works, I checked the versions of application server and the maven jars then I downloaded the latest 2.4.0 jackson jars and upgrade the glassfish lib jars with the 2.4.0 version